# Vuetify - Prevent v-list-item-group De-selection

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a `v-list` and `v-list-item-group` setup very similar to the one shown here in the Vuetify help:

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/lists/#flat

My problem comes if the user clicks on the same `v-list-item` twice - which then de-selects it without selecting another item.

I've tried mapping the `v-model` to a computed `get()`, `set()` and stopping the set, but this doesn't have any effect.

I really want the selected item to be set programmatically and I control it from an `@click` event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to use the `mandatory` property of `v-list-item-group`? It seems to do something close to what you want - the user cannot de-select an item, but can switch to another one. Something like this:

```html
    <v-card class="mx-auto" max-width="300" tile>
      <v-list flat>
        <v-subheader>REPORTS</v-subheader>
        <v-list-item-group v-model="selectedItem" color="primary" mandatory>
          <v-list-item v-for="(item, i) in items" :key="i">
            <v-list-item-icon>
              <v-icon v-text="item.icon"></v-icon>
            </v-list-item-icon>
            <v-list-item-content>
              <v-list-item-title v-text="item.text"></v-list-item-title>
            </v-list-item-content>
          </v-list-item>
        </v-list-item-group>
      </v-list>
    </v-card>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was after

Answer (score 0):

First when user select one item  value of selected Item Group is changed to  new value and when double click still item is selected and active.
Something like this:

```html
<v-list-item-group
                    v-model="selectedItemGroup"
                    :mandatory="selectedItemGroup!=-1"
                  >
</v-list-item-group>


<script>
export default {
data:function(){
 selectedItemGroup:-1,
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).